# Unterschied: "vorübergehen" vs "vorüberkommen" vs "vorbeikommen"?

Tags: meaning, standard-german, difference

Ich wollte die Unterschiede in Benutzung und anderem wissen zw. diesen 3 Wörtern, wenn sie alle in einer und denselber Bedeutung gemeint sind, nämlich "unterwegs an eine Stelle gelangen und weitergehen oder -fahren"??

Comment: "Eines Tages ging ein Mädchen vorüber, das Mädchen riss ein Blattchen ab".
"Kurz danach kam ein Junge vorüber, er brach einen kleinen Zweig ab".
"Da lief ein Ziege vorüber, sie frass ein Stückchen Rinde ab, und ging weiter".
"Und dann ging ein großer Junge vorbei, er hat ein neues Taschenmesser als Geschenk bekommen. Er schnitt die Krone des Bäumchens ab".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- vorüberkommen: ich kann mich nicht erinnern, das jemals gehört zu haben. Höchstens „Komm mal rüber!“, aber ganz bestimmt nicht „komm mal vorüber“.
- vorbeikommen: an einem bestimmten Ort vorbei kommen („ich bin an der Post vorbeigekommen“) oder jemanden besuchen oder einen Ort aufsuchen.
- vorübergehen/vorbeigehen: wie „vorbeikommen“, aber es wird auch oft benutzt, um einen temporären Zustand auszudrücken, zum Beispiel: „Auch diese Krise wird irgendwann vorübergehen“ oder „das geht vorbei“.

Answer (score 1):

"vorüber-" wird mittlerweile seltener benutzt als "vorbei-". Daher im folgenden die Einschränkung auf die Worte "vorbeigehen" und "vorbeikommen".

*vorbeigehen / vorbeifahren*

An eine Stelle / einen Platz gelangen und vorbeigehen - nicht lange warten, sondern kurz registrieren und einfach weiter gehen / fahren.

"Unterwegs auf der Autobahn sind wir an Bielefeld vorbeigefahren." oder "Unterwegs auf der Autobahn fuhren wir an Bielefeld vorbei."

"Entlang meines Weges bin ich an deiner Wohnung vorbeigegangen." oder "Entlang meines Weges ging ich an deiner Wohnung vorbei."

*vorbeikommen*

An eine Stelle / einen Platz gelangen, sehr bewusst registrieren und passieren.

"Unterwegs auf der Autobahn sind wir an Bielefeld vorbeigekommen." oder "Unterwegs auf der Autobahn kamen wir an Bielefeld vorbei."

An einen Platz gelangen und verweilen. Fast immer in Bezug, eine andere Person zu besuchen.

"Entlang meines Weges bin an deiner Wohnung vorbeigekommen." oder "Entlang meines Weges kam ich an deiner Wohnung vorbei."

Und die Besonderheit von vorbeikommen ist die Ankündigung, eine andere Person zu besuchen.

"Ich bin noch unterwegs und komm später vorbei."

*Fazit*

In Bezug auf das Passieren eines bestimmten Punktes sind beide Wörter austauschbar. "vorbeikommen" impliziert die bewusstere Wahrnehmung dieses Punktes.

Frei nach Monty Python: "Und sie kamen am Hügel vorbei und trafen ihre Freunde und ihre Freude war groß!"